# How can I find out what class each of the columns in the probabilities output correspond to using Keras for multi-class classification?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, image-recognition

I'm using transfer learning to build an image recognition model using a pre-trained VGG network in Keras and excluding the final fully-connected layer to get the output weights.  I'm then using these output weights to feed into my new model which has a few layers along with a new fully-connected layer of my own that I'm training. The fully-connected layer maps to the number of output classes that I'm trying to predict.

Everything is working fine.  However, when I run `results = 
 model.predict(img_tensor)` I get output probabilities corresponding to each class, similar to the below:

`print(results)`

```
 [[0.1426621  0.6193871  0.23795079]
 [0.11187755 0.6208466  0.2672758 ]
 [0.10050113 0.3768951  0.52260375]
 [0.1338948  0.59470254 0.27140263]
 [0.06612041 0.69726    0.2366195 ]
 [0.12080433 0.495977   0.38321865]]
```

My question is: **How can I find out what class each of the columns in the probabilities output correspond to?**

Does Keras have anything built-in to identify which column of the output probabilities corresponds to which class?  I would be shocked if nothing is provided...

What have others done to create a work-around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "class_indices" attribute in Keras’ flow_from_directory(directory) creates a dictionary of the classes and their index in the output array:

> classes: optional list of class subdirectories (e.g. [‘dogs’,
>   ‘cats’]). Default: None. If not provided, the list of classes will be
>   automatically inferred from the subdirectory names/structure under
>   directory, where each subdirectory will be treated as a different
>   class (and the order of the classes, which will map to the label
>   indices, will be alphanumeric). The dictionary containing the mapping
>   from class names to class indices can be obtained via the attribute
>   class_indices.

Source: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

I would be interested to see how people have incorporated this into their workflow/scripts though...